# How to host a project on Launchpad?

Tags: application-development, ppa, launchpad

I want to create a Python project and host it on Launchpad. I have already produced Python code. What I want to know is:

1. How can put it on Launchpad?
2. How can I make a PPA for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. How can I put it on Launchpad?

- First you should [register your project](https://help.launchpad.net/Projects/Registering);
- then you can [configure code hosting and push your code](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/QuickStart);
- you may also want to [configure the bug tracker](https://help.launchpad.net/Bugs/YourProject).

#### 2. How can I make a PPA for it?

The Launchpad documentation tells you how to [create a PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA). It does not tell you however how to create Debian/Ubuntu packages. This topic is covered by the [Ubuntu packaging guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/).

You can automate the creation of Ubuntu packages from Bazaar branches using [packaging recipes](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/GettingStarted).

#### Other stuff

For more information, here are three helpful links:

- the [Launchpad help](https://help.launchpad.net/);
- the [Ubuntu packaging tools](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/packaging/);
- the [Ubuntu developer porta](http://developer.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: I know how to make a PPA. I previously made one with quickly. I want to know how to associate a PPA with a project(manually).

Comment: @apandada1: you have to put a link to the PPA in your project's description. There are no other ways: PPAs belong to people and teams, not to projects.

Comment: That's not the point. I want to know how to take the code into a PPA after hosting the code on Launchpad.

Comment: @apandada1: I can't understand what you mean... perhaps you want to **automate** the creation of Ubuntu packages from Bazaar branches? If so, you are looking for **[packaging recipes](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/GettingStarted)**.